# workflow foundation multiple tracking participants do not work consistently

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, workflow-foundation

I have trouble with custom workflow foundation tracking participants in wf4.5 and C# v4.0.30319 running under win7. A single tracking participant seems to work reliable, but as soon as i use a second tracking participant i becomes a game of luck if the activity is tracked or not.
I have checked out every possible stack overflow answer and probably every available google result.

I have created a simple application to demonstrate the behavior.

I have a simple code activity:

```
using System;
using System.Activities;

namespace WorkflowTrackingTestApp
{
    public sealed class CodeActivity1 : CodeActivity
    {
        public InArgument<string> Text { get; set; }

        protected override void Execute( CodeActivityContext context )
        {
            Console.WriteLine( "executing code activity " + typeof( string ).Assembly.ImageRuntimeVersion );
        }
    }
}
```

It does nothing but printing "executing code activity and the c# version".

Than i have two custom tracking participants. Notice that they both have a tracking profile and the profiles have different names, since it was suggested in another thread that this might be the issue.

```
namespace ActivityLibrary
{
    using System;
    using System.Activities.Tracking;

    public class EventTrackingParticipant0 : TrackingParticipant
    {
        public EventTrackingParticipant0()
        {
            this.TrackingProfile = new TrackingProfile
            {
                Name = "CustomTrackingProfile0",
                Queries =
                {
                    new WorkflowInstanceQuery
                    {
                        // Limit workflow instance tracking records for started and
                        // completed workflow states.
                        States = {WorkflowInstanceStates.Started, WorkflowInstanceStates.Completed},
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public Action<TrackingRecord> Received { get; set; }

        protected override void Track( TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout )
        {
            if( Received != null )
            {
                Received.BeginInvoke( record, BeginInvokeCallback, Received );
            }
        }

        private void BeginInvokeCallback( IAsyncResult ar )
        {
            ((Action<TrackingRecord>)ar.AsyncState).EndInvoke( ar );
        }
    }

    public class EventTrackingParticipant1 : TrackingParticipant
    {
        public EventTrackingParticipant1()
        {
            this.TrackingProfile = new TrackingProfile
            {
                Name = "CustomTrackingProfile1",
                Queries =
                {
                    new WorkflowInstanceQuery
                    {
                        // Limit workflow instance tracking records for started and
                        // completed workflow states.
                        States = {WorkflowInstanceStates.Started, WorkflowInstanceStates.Completed},
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public Action<TrackingRecord> Received { get; set; }

        protected override void Track( TrackingRecord record, TimeSpan timeout )
        {
            if( Received != null )
            {
                Received.BeginInvoke( record, BeginInvokeCallback, Received );
            }
        }

        private void BeginInvokeCallback( IAsyncResult ar )
        {
            ((Action<TrackingRecord>)ar.AsyncState).EndInvoke( ar );
        }

    }
}
```

For both profiles the code is basically the same.

Now to the main program:

```
namespace WorkflowTrackingTestApp
{
    using System;
    using System.Activities;
    using ActivityLibrary;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            EventTrackingParticipant0 tp0 = new EventTrackingParticipant0();
            tp0.Received = tr => Console.WriteLine( "tracker0 tracking " + tr.EventTime.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) + " " + tr.RecordNumber);

            EventTrackingParticipant1 tp1 = new EventTrackingParticipant1();
            tp1.Received = tr => Console.WriteLine( "tracker1 tracking " + tr.EventTime.ToString( CultureInfo.InvariantCulture ) + " " + tr.RecordNumber );

            Activity workflow1 = new CodeActivity1();
            WorkflowInvoker wfInvoker = new WorkflowInvoker( workflow1 );

            //add tracking participants
            wfInvoker.Extensions.Add( tp0 );
            wfInvoker.Extensions.Add( tp1 );

            wfInvoker.Invoke( );
        }
    }
}
```

It adds the two tracking participants and executes the code activity.
This are some of the possible results:

```
executing code activity v4.0.30319
tracker0 tracking 08/26/2015 09:18:50 0
tracker1 tracking 08/26/2015 09:18:50 0
Press any key to continue . . .

executing code activity v4.0.30319
tracker0 tracking 08/26/2015 09:29:41 0
tracker0 tracking 08/26/2015 09:29:41 4
tracker1 tracking 08/26/2015 09:29:41 0
tracker1 tracking 08/26/2015 09:29:41 4
Press any key to continue . . .

executing code activity v4.0.30319
tracker0 tracking 08/26/2015 09:30:08 0
tracker1 tracking 08/26/2015 09:30:08 0
tracker0 tracking 08/26/2015 09:30:08 4
tracker1 tracking 08/26/2015 09:30:08 4
Press any key to continue . . .

executing code activity v4.0.30319
tracker0 tracking 08/26/2015 09:30:25 0
tracker1 tracking 08/26/2015 09:30:25 0
tracker1 tracking 08/26/2015 09:30:25 4
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Does anyone know whats could be the reason for such behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Tracking participatns are executed asynchronously, usually not in the same thread with activities execution. Your console application sometimes just exits before one of participants has time to execute. For example, if you add simple
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
after wfInvoker.Invoke( ); you will get all 4 handlers beeing executed almost always.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Thread.Sleep seems to me like a kind of "dirty" solution. Is there a way to make the tracking participants synchronous?

Answer (score 1):

Change implementation of Track methods from

```
  if( Received != null )
  {
      Received.BeginInvoke( record, BeginInvokeCallback, Received );
  }
```

to

```
  if (Received != null)
      Received(record);
```

In this case tracking participants will be executed in the same thread as activities.